Problem when styling django form fields upon errors
I have a bug I've been trying to fix for months but can't figure out.
I'm building a website with Django. The site has a form, that, among other fields, has a field to input the name (called "nombre") and a field for the last name (called "apellido") of the user.
I've declared a CSS rule (applied to the fields with the class "error" that gives a specific style to the fields that didn't pass the form validation, highlighting them in red.
In a "forms.py" file, I wrote some code that assigns the class "error" to the fields that did not pass the validation.
The problem is that, when I input invalid data into the "apellido" field and try to submit the form, both de "apellido" and "nombre" fields get highlighted in red.
I have no clue why this could be happening. I figure it must be something with the "forms.py" file, where I assign the "error" class to the invalid fields.
Here is the code of the "forms.py" file:
from django import forms
from .models import Turno

class TurnoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
class Meta:
    model = Turno
    fields = ['nombre', 'apellido', 'email', 'fecha', 'hora']
    widgets = {
        "nombre": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control", "name": "nombre"}),
        "apellido": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control", "name": "apellido"}),
        "email": forms.EmailInput(attrs={"class": "form-control", "name": "email"}),
    }
            
def clean_nombre(self):
    nombre = self.cleaned_data["nombre"]

    if not nombre.isalpha():
        self.fields["nombre"].widget.attrs["class"] += " error"
        raise forms.ValidationError("Por favor, ingrese solo caracteres alfabéticos", code="carac_esp")
        
    
    return nombre

def clean_apellido(self):
    """
    El fallo está en este campo. Al completarlo erróneamente se marca también el campo de "nombre" como incorrecto.
    """
    apellido = self.cleaned_data["apellido"]

    if not apellido.isalpha():
        self.fields["apellido"].widget.attrs["class"] += " error"
        raise forms.ValidationError("Por favor, ingrese solo caracteres alfabéticos", code="carac_esp")
    
    return apellido

Do you think the problem is somewhere in there?

Please check out this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#styling-required-or-erroneous-form-rows hook, may this helps you, with this you just need to define error_css_class and not required to add same class in each clean method

Please don't repost your questions. See: What should I do if no one answers my question?. Edit your old question if you want to provide any clarifications. I don't think both this and your previous question have a proper [mre]. Try to reproduce your problem with just HTML and CSS to begin with.
